# How to dynamically wrap existing functions, such as for a profiler?

Tags: function, macros, lisp, sbcl

I am new at Lisp, and am trying different things out to improve my skills. I want to write a macro that wraps existing functions so that I can set up before and after forms for these functions, kind of like CLOS's auxilliary methods or Elisp's advice package. The trace function's ability to wrap code dynamically has intrigued me, and it seems useful to be able to do this myself.

How can I do this?

Please note that I am using SBCL, and that, for the purposes of this question, I am not interested so much in the "right" way of doing this as I am in adding to my Lisp trick bag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any built-in support for this outside of CLOS. But you could just redefine the original function, like this:

```
(defmacro add-post (fun-name &body body)
  (let ((orig (gensym)))
    `(let ((,orig (fdefinition ,fun-name))) 
       (setf (fdefinition ,fun-name) (lambda (&rest args)
                                       (apply ,orig args)
                                       ,@body)))))
```

Comment: Question: does Common Lisp allow implementations to compile a function that references the compile-time fdefinitions of called function rather than making it look up the fdefinition at runtime? If it does, then swapping out the fdefinition won't necessarily work (presumably unless `(optimize debug)` was in effect).

Comment: I think the same restrictions apply that are specified for `trace` in the CLHS: "If a function to be traced has been open-coded (e.g., because it was declared inline), a call to that function might not produce trace output. " But that's the special case, usually function definitions should be looked up at runtime. That kind of late-binding is after all what makes Lisp a dynamic language.

Comment: This worked well, even as a function.  However, I had to use ',fun-name instead of just ,fun-name in each location in your code.

Comment: @gamecoder: Yes, I assumed the function name would be quoted by the user of the macro, but by quoting in the macro definition you've made that unnecessary.